# Coded UI - Cannot access controls on browser1 after switch from browser2

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

I am not able to access controls on the Browser1 (IE) after I switch from Browser2 (Chrome)

The scenario is:

1. Open http://login.live.com in IE
2. Open http://login.live.com in Chrome
3. Click on Sign in button on Chrome
4. Come back to IE & Click on Sign in button

I have written below code snippet.

```
    public static BrowserWindow CurrentBrowser = null, Chrome = null, IE = null; 

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        IE = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

        BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
        Chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

        CurrentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("Chrome");

        HtmlControl LogOnButton = new HtmlControl(CurrentBrowser);
        LogOnButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "idSIButton9");
        Mouse.Click(LogOnButton);


        CurrentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("IE");
        CurrentBrowser.SetFocus();

        Mouse.Click(LogOnButton);  // Here, it clicks the Sign in button on Chrome. Not on IE
    }

  public static BrowserWindow GetMeTheBrowserIWant(string BrowserType)
    {
        if(BrowserType.ToUpper().Equals("CHROME"))
        {
           return Chrome;
        } 

        if(BrowserType.ToUpper().Equals("IE"))
        {
           return IE;
        } 

        return null;
    }
```

But at the last step even though I have set CurrentBrowser to "IE", it is clicking on "Sign in" button on Chrome browser.

Any way to make it click "Sign in" on "IE" browser?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a flaw in your test code your search limit container hasn't been updated

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    IE = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

    BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
    Chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

    CurrentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("Chrome");
```

At this point the definition of your current browser is a chrome window

```
    HtmlControl LogOnButton = new HtmlControl(CurrentBrowser);
    LogOnButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "idSIButton9");
    Mouse.Click(LogOnButton);
```

you may be overriding the field but the chrome browser is still referencing the chrome window

```
    CurrentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("IE");
    CurrentBrowser.SetFocus();
```

Now as currently written this is actually working as expected -> go click the login button **IN** chrome, because you defined it inside a chrome window;

```
    Mouse.Click(LogOnButton);  
}
```

You can either assign its container again or create a new logon button.

```
LogonButton.Container = CurrentBrowser;
// or
var buttonInIE = new HtmlControl(IEBW);
var buttonInChrome = new HtmlControl(ChromeBW);
```

Remember Codedui is based on controls within controls

Answer (score 0):

**If** the flow is as above - open IE, Open Chrome, Sign in to Chrome and Sign into IE, you could use the following to locate your IE browser

**BrowserWindow.Locate("SiteTitle")** - This locates the browser window by the title defined. Note that Locate only works for IE and not Chrome.

Once you locate the IE browser and click on sign, the Sign in action takes place on the IE browser.

Your code should be:

```
public class IEAndChrome
  {
    private BrowserWindow currentBrowser = null;
    private BrowserWindow chrome = null;
    private BrowserWindow iE = null;

    public BrowserWindow Browser { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
      iE = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

      BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
      chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://login.live.com"));

      currentBrowser = GetMeTheBrowserIWant("Chrome");

      HtmlControl logOnButton = new HtmlControl(currentBrowser);
      logOnButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id,      "idSIButton9");
      Mouse.Click(logOnButton);



      currentBrowser = BrowserWindow.Locate("Sign in to your Microsoft account");

      Mouse.Click(logOnButton);  // Here, it clicks the Sign in button on Chrome. Not on IE
    }
```

This should work for you, verified it

Comment: Ive not used this before, but i read somewhere that **EnumWindows** may work as well for multiple window management. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx